# How to make a function pick a random number without repeating numbers, then start over once its gone through every number?

Tags: javascript, random

I'm doing some self practice/study with JavaScript. I am creating a quote generator. I have an array of quote objects. Right now, my function randomly chooses an object out of the array and posts a quote with this code.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    for (obj of quoteList)
        rando = quoteList[Math.floor(Math.random() * quoteList.length)];
    author.innerHTML = `~${rando.author}`;
    quote.innerHTML = rando.quote;
});
```

- The problem is that I noticed that sometimes I can click the button to get a new quote and by random chance the same quote may pop up 3 times in a row at times. How can I ensure this never happens? How can I reorder the permutations then have it loop through again once it has exhausted all of the objects in the array?

Answer (score 1):

This is my proposal
See  comments in the code

It basically uses a curried function which stores the quotes array in a shuffled order. The curries function returns an object which contains a function `nextQuote` as only member. This function steps through the shuffled array and shuffles it again, if it reaches the end beginning the journey anew.

```js
console.clear()

{
  "use strict";
  // Saves the quotes in a closure and returns an object with one function (`nextQuote`)
  const initQuotes = ([...quotes]) => {
    let index = 0

    // Helper function that shuffles the quotes array
    const shuffleQuotes = () => quotes.sort((a, b) => Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) * 2 - 1) // randomly -1 or 1

    // Advances to the next quote and shuffles if at the end
    const nextQuote = () => {
      const curr = quotes[index++]
      if (index >= quotes.length) {
        index = 0;
        shuffleQuotes();
      }
      return curr
    };

    // initially shuffle quotes
    shuffleQuotes();

    return {nextQuote}

  }
  // Make this available in global scope
  window.Quotes = initQuotes;
}

// Event Management
{
  "use strict";
  const buttonId = "next"
  const buttonSelector = `#${buttonId}`
  const authorId = "author"
  const authorSelector = `#${authorId}`
  const quoteId = "quote"
  const quoteSelector = `#${quoteId}`


  const onClick = e => {
    const button = e.target.closest(buttonSelector)
    if (!button) {
      return true
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateQuote(myQuotes.nextQuote())
  }

  const updateQuote = quote => {
    document.getElementById(authorId).innerHTML = quote.author;
    document.getElementById(quoteId).innerHTML = quote.quote;
  };

  const quotes = [
    {quote: 'Always remember that you are absolutely unique. Just like everyone else.',author: 'Margaret Mead'},
    {quote: 'Tell me and I forget. Teach me and I remember. Involve me and I learn.',author: 'Benjamin Franklin'},
    {quote: 'Whoever is happy will make others happy too.',author: 'Anne Frank'},
    {quote: 'You miss 100% of the shots you don\'t take.',author: 'Wayne Gretzky'},
  ]
  // calls the Quotes function from aboce. which returns an object with the nextQuote function
  const myQuotes = Quotes(quotes)
  updateQuote(myQuotes.nextQuote())
  
  document.addEventListener('click', onClick)

}
```

```css
#author {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<button id="next">Next quote</button>
<div id="quote"></div>
<div id="author"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array which contains all the unused quotes, and remove that element from the array after you've used it:

```
const quoteList = [...];
const unusedQuotes = [...quoteList];
// ...

for (let i = 0; i < quoteList.length; i++) {
    random = unusedQuotes.splice( Math.floor(Math.random() * unusedQuotes.length), 1)[0];
}
```

By the way, there's no point in using a `for of` if you're not going to use the object, it's better to use a regular `for` loop in this case.